# mat select is sticky on mobile web

Tags: angular, mobile, angular-material

Anyone knows how to disable mat select being sticky on mobile web?
this can be reproduced on iphone (maybe other mobile devices) on angular material official site
once options are open then try scrolling the page and the options stick and sort of scroll with the page

Answer (score 1):

1. Try giving the `mat-select` an attribute of `[sticky]='false'`

   or
2. Try around with `position` of the `mat-select` in `css`.

Comment: yeah there is no such option for mat-select

Comment: I'm not to sure what you are trying to do. Is the issue that they are scrolling out of the page? Inside `mat-select` place an `ng-container` for your `mat-options` to go inside. `[sticky]='false'` attribute on the ng-container should work. This may fix the issue you are having. If you could provide code to repeat the issue it could be helpful.

Comment: this is the issue
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/879

Comment: Ah I think I understand. It seems the MDC Select uses a native approach and creates some issue with the scrolling. Check out the material website [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#select-overview). `mat-select` component locks the screen until the user either selects an option or clicks off the select box. Hopefully this helps and gives an output you are looking for.

Comment: it locks for desktop, but for mobile device like iphone scrolling cannot be locked just like that, as a result the selection scrolls with the page
try to checkout angular-material web site with an iphone and go to mat-select, it will happen as well (i am using iphonexs)

Answer (score 0):

For now i have created a directive for mat-select that will collapse the mat-select on 'touchmove', so it will be consistent with web desktop where scrolling is blocked, in this case the select will just collapse as if user clicked away on the screen, and keeping the select open if it is within mat-select to allow users to scroll through options
if there is a better solution to this please post